# Plotly - Change colors of specific bars

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I have a data frame in the following format:

[image: Dataframe]

I want to create a group bar chart like this:

[image: Expected]

I am able to produce the following chart in the Plotly using the following code:

```
abc = pd.read_csv('bar dara.csv')
colors    = ['#ED7D31','#EF995F','#FFD68A','#FFA500','#FFB52E','#FFC55C','#FF6347','#FF4500','#FF7F50']

fig = px.bar(abc, x='Column A', y='Column C',
             color=abc['Column B'], barmode='group',
             text=abc['Column C'].astype(str),
             color_discrete_sequence=colors)

fig.update_layout(title_text='abcd', title_x=0.5,title_font_color='#ED7D31')
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title='ylabel')
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis_title="Column C")

fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:,}')
# Don't forget to remove from update_traces
fig.update_traces(textfont_size=12)
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:,}')
fig.update_yaxes(tickformat=",d")
fig.show()
```

[image: Actual]

Can you please help me in letting me know how to change color of the bar for the column bars corresponding to A1?

Comment: I can't think of a way to change the color of the first bar in the grouping. If you check the data, you will understand that we use one color for the group. type `fig.data`

Comment: @r-beginners I had an idea that we will plot the secondary axis where the bar groups for A1, A2, A3, A4 and A5 will be plotted and then hide the secondary axis. But not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution, but you can use plot the bars separately: create `fig1` for the bars corresponding to `A1`, and create `fig2` for all of the other bars. Then you can create `fig3` combining the data from fig1 and fig2.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

abc = pd.DataFrame({
    "Column A":["A1"]*2+["A2"]*4+["A3"]*4+["A4"]*4+["A5"]*4,
    "Column B":["B1","B2"]+["B1","B2","B3","B4"]*4,
    "Column C":[12,10,14,12,10,8,10,8,6,4,9,7,5,3,6,4,2,0]
})

abc_a1_bars = abc[abc["Column A"] == "A1"]
abc_non_a1_bars = abc[abc["Column A"] != "A1"]

colors = ['#ED7D31','#EF995F','#FFD68A','#FFA500','#FFB52E','#FFC55C','#FF6347','#FF4500','#FF7F50']

fig1 = px.bar(abc_a1_bars, x='Column A', y='Column C',
             color=abc_a1_bars['Column B'], barmode='group',
             text=abc_a1_bars['Column C'].astype(str),
             color_discrete_sequence=["grey","#FFD68A"])
fig1.update_traces(showlegend=False)

fig2 = px.bar(abc_non_a1_bars, x='Column A', y='Column C',
             color=abc_non_a1_bars['Column B'], barmode='group',
             text=abc_non_a1_bars['Column C'].astype(str),
             color_discrete_sequence=colors)

fig3 = go.Figure(data=fig1.data + fig2.data)

fig3.update_layout(title_text='abcd', title_x=0.5,title_font_color='#ED7D31')
fig3.update_layout(
    xaxis_title='ylabel')
fig3.update_layout(
    yaxis_title="Column C")

fig3.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:,}')
# Don't forget to remove from update_traces
fig3.update_traces(textfont_size=12)
fig3.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:,}')
fig3.update_yaxes(tickformat=",d")
fig3.show()
```

[image]